# What specific Regex does Castle Validator ValidateEmail use?

Tags: regex, validation, castle-activerecord, castle

I have two interacting systems in one we are using Castle Validator for our validation, the other is coded by hand, I need to ensure the email validation between these two systems is a match; the problem is I have not been able to find documentation of the Regex that castle uses for email.

There is [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1281092/castle-validateemail-attribute-fails-on-plus-sign) but the links provided are all dead.

Comment: 1. Clone https://github.com/castleproject/Core 2. Look up EmailValidator in the repo history.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking through the repo history I was able to find the regex (separated into multiple lines for readability):

```
^([a-zA-z0-9_\-\.\'\+]+)
@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.)+))
([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$
```

A side note: this regex is still pretty broken with how the `@[ipaddress]` is allowed.

For example this: `johndoe@mydomain.111]` is registered as valid as would this: `johndoe@[111.111.111.com`